# Weird Exception while using DataGridView and possibly Multi-Threads

Tags: winforms, multithreading

I followed google to this MSDN forum [thread](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3905448&SiteID=1).

The last answer was and I qoute : "Using threads? Don't"

Does someone knows a walk around?

As far as I can tell, I'm playing the cards well.
I'm using BeginInvoke inorder to populate the data source inside the UI thread.

More details :

I've got a background thread that make queries to a Sql Compact edition DB using LINQ to SQL.

After that I'm calling the method that would have updated the DataSource with BeginInvoke:

Comment: Could you rewrite the question as a question, and include a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1):

if you're doing that then use the background worker component and on its report progress event populate your grid with already returned data.

Comment: I'm using it, but as I said it's a weird exception